# Modal Form is showing not as Modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc

New here. I have Index.cshtml where tags looks like below calling _ModalFormSample.cshtml via button.

```
 @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  }
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
            <a href="@Url.Action("ModalFormSample", "Home", new {timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()})" class="btn btn-info showModal">Add Account</a>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

_ModalFormSample.cshtml

```
<div class="modal" id="modalFormSample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting that _ModalFormSample will display as a modal form when clicking Add Account button but it didn't.

What Am I missing here? I using VS 2019 C#.Net

Comment: So what's happening here? Does it redirect to `/Home/ModalFormSample` url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to display `modal` dynamically, you will need to write `js` code to achieve what you want.

1. Add one div where you can append response div of your expected modal. Here I have added div with id `myModal`.
2. Write `.showModal` click event function as below. Explanation is there in comment.

```js
// showModal button click event
$(".showModal").click(function(e) {

  // to stop redirecting to href url
  e.preventDefault();

  // fetch url from href
  let url = $(this).attr("href");

  // do ajax call and append response in myModal div.
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
      // Append response in myModal div
      $('#myModal').html(response);
      // show modal
      $('#modalFormSample').modal('show');
    },
    dataType: "html"
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
      <a href="@Url.Action(" ModalFormSample ", "Home ", new {timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()})" class="btn btn-info showModal">Add Account</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal"></div>
```

Comment: How to use this as code snippet for all modal forms in the entire app?

Comment: Then you may want to add this into your `Layout` page which is common across all pages in application.